# My program jumps straight to else in a long string of if/elif/else and won't do its job

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement

This is the 1st segment of the decoding script(in a sense, they all are the same except 3 characters and there are several HUNDRED more) and it DOES NOT find a proper character.

```
#Only one I'll comment, as they are the same except in the converted character.
    if(str(fin.readline().rstrip('\n')) == "2A"):#If the read string *WITHOUT NEWLINES* is found on the current line, then convert it.
        converted = "A"#Decoded character.
        fout.write(converted)#Write to memory
        loop = loop - 1#Decrease characters left
        print str(loop) + " characters to decode!"#Useful information output.
        time.sleep(0.1024)#Slow down the program!
        fout.flush()#Save output.
```

Here is my encoded file:

```
17
F4
F5
DD
FC
ED
FE
EF
FF
F1
F4
F3
FC
F1
ED
EC
FF
F4
```

First line here is the number of encoded characters.

Here's the original...

```
klzsdufvhkjshdcvk
```

Here's the else and end of my while loop:

```
    else:
        exit()
fout.close()
fin.close()
print "Exiting..."
time.sleep(3.237465790263490545790869475236789568234795692348975634789695436895689763874567)
print "Done!!!"
time.sleep(1.20745)
exit()
```

Comment: `time.sleep(3.237465790263490545790869475236789568234795692348975634789695436895689763874567)` this seems odd

Comment: @TimCastelijns I just made a big float. IDK why. I just did it for LOLs.